# Blue/green SMD resistor

Tags: resistors

What does the blue color of  **SMD** resistors mean?
I saw a board with blue colored body resistors (and another one with green) as part of high voltage measuring circuit, so I am trying to figure if these resistors are special in some sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They may well be special high precision, high resistance and/or high voltage resistors, but there is no standard coding for such features.

High precision (0.01%) resistors from Vishay are often robin's egg blue. I've seen non-magnetic resistors that are green.

It would help with inspection since such resistors may otherwise look the same as ordinary cheap resistors of the same physical size.

Answer (score 3):

The existing answer is more than adequate, I am just adding some example series:

VSMP: probably the aforementioned robin's egg blue, VPG precision

TNPU: deep blue, very precision

MC AT: deep blue, standard

RK73H: light blue, standard

MC: mint green, precision

TNPW: green, precision (seems popular as well)

TNPV: green, no marking even on larger packages, precision high voltage.

SG73P-RT: green, pulse withstanding thick film